# Running C program from Sublime Text 2 in windows

Tags: windows, editor, sublimetext

I have installed Sublime text 2 in windows 7. I want to run C program in it.I am using borland compiler. I couldn't understood build system option.Please help,give me the command to run c++ program. Using cmd I compile it as "bcc32 program_name.c" and then run as program_name.exe  .

Comment: Have you tried asking in the [Sublime Text forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/)?

Comment: Take a look at the Zeus editor. I use it for my C/C++ coding and it works well. In particular if you search the Zeus forum you'll find many examples of how to do these sort of things.

Answer (score 0):

The way I was running applications on Windows with Sublime Text 2 was through a custom build script. I made a Windows Batch file and did all of the things I wanted to do in that batch file. Then all I had to do was use the Build shortcut key to run the batch file.

The custom build script referenced the bat file with the absolute path, just in-case you run into any problems if you do try this out...

Comment: I just removed borland compiler and now using gcc. and it is working well. Thanks for ur help.